# environment variable in scripts with heredoc

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables

**script: t1.sh**

```
DEST=`mktemp -d`
echo "DEST=$DEST"
```

**script: t2.sh**

```
sudo -s <<EOF
DEST=`mktemp -d`
echo "DEST=$DEST"
EOF
```

invoking `t1.sh`, with or without `sudo`:

```
$ bash t1.sh
DEST=/tmp/tmp.3PxGIYutDj

$ sudo bash t1.sh
DEST=/tmp/tmp.GpYT3fApCW
```

invoking `t2.sh`:

```
$ bash t2.sh
DEST=
```

Why the `$DEST` variable is not set in `t2.sh`?  BTW, I am using Debian 10.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. Quote the delimiter:

```
sudo -s <<"EOF"
DEST=`mktemp -d`
echo "DEST=$DEST"
EOF
```